# Mac OS X xampp mysql and proftpd not working

Tags: mysql, macos, xampp

I have decided to start with laravel and successfully installed it in my mac but the problem is I can't connect to my localhost/phpmyadmin because XAMPP wont make mysql start and proftpd.

Here's the log

`Starting MySQL Database...
Starting Apache Web Server...
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/apache2/scripts/ctl.sh : httpd started
Starting ProFTPD...
Exit code: 8
Stdout:
Checking syntax of configuration file
proftpd config test fails, aborting
Stderr:
2020-04-24 15:42:55,322 mypc-2 proftpd[22004]: warning: unable to determine IP address of 'mypc-2'
2020-04-24 15:42:55,322 mypc-2 proftpd[22004]: error: no valid servers configured
2020-04-24 15:42:55,322 mypc-2 proftpd[22004]: fatal: error processing configuration file '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/proftpd.conf'`

and I dont know why it says `mypc-2` when it should only be `mypc`

Comment: you could try looking at the proftpd.conf and check it against another to see if there's a problem with the syntax. Also, you should be able to change mypc-2 to mypc.

Comment: I solved it by reinstalling everything I uninstalled xampp